# Overriding a method of an inner class of a parent class

Tags: c#, overriding, inner-classes

I am a C# novice, attempting to override a method, with limited ability to change the base class...

The original class:

```
class Foo
    protected class Tool
       public virtual Frog() {...}
```

My extension:

```
class MyFoo : Foo
    // some special sauce? then:
    public virtual Frog() {...}
```

Within `MyFoo`, I get syntax errors from:

```
protected class Tool     { public override Frog() {...} }
protected class Foo.Tool { public override Frog() {...} }
public override Tool.Frog() {...}
```

So, is this at all doable? 
If not, what is the least change to `class Tool` that does?

Comment: the implementation of `Frog` in the `MyFoo` class must use the keyword `override` not `virtual`.

Comment: You will have to descend from `Tool` as well, you cannot override the methods with `Tool.Frog`, that won't work.

Comment: Nested classes aren't usually very useful. And inheritance, while useful at times, is overused and can give you headaches. Nothing good can come from combining them.